# Use Ruby Mechanize to simulate file uploading by Flash

Tags: ruby, file-upload, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I want to use Ruby Mechanize to write an auto file uploading script for a website. But the read upload step of the website is done by a Flash file. I use ***fiddler*** captured the traffic from the Flash file to the server. Here is it.

```
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------KM7KM7Ij5KM7KM7ei4GI3GI3gL6GI3
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Host: 119.147.15.17<this is fake IP address>
Content-Length: 7800236
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

------------KM7KM7Ij5KM7KM7ei4GI3GI3gL6GI3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

learning_objectives.flv
------------KM7KM7Ij5KM7KM7ei4GI3GI3gL6GI3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileData"; filename="learning_objectives.flv"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

This_is_the_real_data_in_learning_objectives.flv
```

My question is how can I simulate this post requrest? Currently what I can think of is create a form by myself and add an input element with type ***file***. Then submit this form with customized headers (such as the user-agent etc.). But I'm still have difficult in dealing with the file upload part. Anyone can help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the mechanize code to figure out how it handles multipart forms? You should be able to adapt the code used there to send a custom multipart request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
agent.post url, 'FileData' => File.new('learning_objectives.flv')
```